# Write permission for external sd card in android 4.0

Tags: android, xml, permissions, android-sdcard

I am facing a problem while trying to write a files into External SD Card in `android 4.0.3`,even I have made use of the write permissions like `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` & `WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE`, So I have found another way to work on it, but now I want to find out whether my app is possible to write into the Removable SD Card
 or not, if not then I would like to switch to Internal SD Card.

So now the question is how will I come to know whether writing into Removable SD Card supported or not, So if anyone has done any similar kind of an implementation please feel free to share the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer directly from the API guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

```
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // We can read and write the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // We can only read the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
        //  to know is we can neither read nor write
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Budius, the link that you had provided was quiet useful for me, let me try it and accordingly I will let you know whether it works in my code.

Comment: The external storage functions only point to the manufacturers sdcard. It may or may not be removable. The 'real' removable sdcards have to be tested with a roll your own function or class. After you find the directory that is the removable device you  want, use a File temp = File("/mnt/theExternalSDCard"); and then check it out for temp.exists(), temp.isDirecotory(), temp.canRead(), and temp.canWrite. If it passes the tests, you're gold.

Comment: This is **not the answer** for most 4.x+ devices contemporary and subsequent to when it was written, where the "External Storage" is not an SD card.  Typically today, the External Storage is implemented with space borrowed as needed from internal flash chips.  An additional SD card, if present on a vendor device, tends to be mounted at a different location.

Answer (score 1):

I have an app that writes to both the internal and external SD cards. I have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, but nothing else.

The main problem in dealing with the external SD card is to find the path, because `getExternalStorageDirectory()` usually returns the internal one. It should be a subdirectory of `/mnt`, if that helps.

Comment: Thank you Philip for the answer it helped, but I have a question for you, have you tried writing into an SD card for Android 3.0 and above because according to my info it is not allowed by google itself. So if you have worked on it then what all have you done to Write into SD Card can you please share the part of code if you don't mind.       Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tested my app on every version from 2.1 to 4.0.3. What makes you think that it is not allowed? That would not make any sense. You obviously have a problem, but you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Philip I am talking about writing into Removable SD Card.

Comment: Yes of course, and you are not succeeding. But it is not a system issue - it is an application issue.

Answer (score 0):

To find if you can write to SD card take a look at the `Environment` class.

```
String externalStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

you can then check this state using

`Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED(externalStorageState)` and/or `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY`(externalStorageState)

Comment: Thanks Gheese, I will try your way and accordingly will tell you what I got.

Comment: **Caution** this does not typically refer to an actual SD card and so is not applicable to the specific case of the question.